# "lots of theory" or "lot of theories"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, idioms

I wrote this sentence, and I'm wondering if I should say "lots of theory" or "lots of theories". Which is correct?

> Time  after time **lots of theory** and experiments made their assumption wrong and this overcome came because of getting proper knowledge about the gravity and employing that successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Theory*** can be both a countable and an uncountable noun, so both "*lots of theory*" and "*lots of theories*" can be correct, but they mean slightly different things.

In its countable form, *a theory* is a hypothesis about how something works that can lead to the design of experiments or predictions, or (*esp. in mathematics*) a collection of propositions that together form a model of how something works which can be investigated independently to give results relevant to that theory.

> There are *a lot of theories* about how the universe started.
>
> There are *a lot of theories* about where and when life originated.
>
> The students had *a lot of different theories* about why the mixture turned purple after we added the litmus.

In its uncountable form, *theory* (as opposed to *practice*) refers to non-experimental study of a subject. For instance, a *theoretical physicist* is a physicist who only does *theory* of physics, and does not generally perform *experiments* (unlike an *experimental* physicist).

> I took a Math III course with Professor Widget - there was *a lot of theory* in his courses!
>
> I took Professor Handson's class instead of Professor Thinkalot's because Thinkalot's classes always have *too much theory* for my liking.

Looking at your specific case, you're talking about *theories*, not *theory* because you are talking about *specific hypothesis and models* which had bad assumptions, rather than suggesting that *non-experimental analysis* (and hence science itself) is inherently flawed and always had bad assumptions.

> Time after time ***lots of theories*** and experiments have made wrong assumptions, but this was eventually overcome by getting better knowledge and employing that knowledge successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I am a graduate student of mathematics, so I read of various theories relatively often. It seems to me that both options would be correct, but would convey a slightly different meaning.

If you say "lots of theories", this suggests that you are looking at the different theories, one at a time, and you state that some of these theories made wrong assumptions. For example, you may assume Newton's equations of motion, and say that these assumptions give you a theory (of, say, classical mechanics). In this context, I think "the theory" could be replaced with "a branch of physics".

If you say "lots of theory", this suggests that you are looking at the theory as a whole, and you state that different fragments of this greater whole made wrong assumptions. For example, if I were to propose an axiom that all bodies fall with equal speed (which is nonsence), this would be a bit of theory that gets its assumptions wrong (but "the theory" as a whole may still be full of valid statements). In this context, I think "the theory" could be replaced with "the theoretical physics".